# How does Should/Could/Might/... affect the following verbs

Tags: should, could

Which sentence is correct?

(1) One should avoid the configurations indicated by (i) and (ii), and focus**es** on setting the values of ....

(2) One should avoid the configurations indicated by (i) and (ii), and focus on setting the values of ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is almost certainly that the "focus" is still within the scope of "should", so it takes the infinitive just like "avoid".

It is possible to come up with a superficially similar example, where the second verb is not within the scope of "should", and so does not take the infinitive:

> He should not drink tonight, and makes sure there are only soft drinks in the fridge.